# What is base argument used for in ParseInt()?

Tags: go

I have come across many sample code whenever we try to convert string to int we use :

```
parseValue, err := strconv.ParseInt(value, 10, 64)
```

So the code above `ParseInt()` has three arguments. from the documentation code :

```
func ParseInt(s string, base int, bitSize int) (i int64, err error) {
```

I tried to understand the `base int`here so I change the value from 0 to 16. [PlayGolang](https://play.golang.org/p/TfZApCpqfx).

The result is ok when the input are `0` and `10`. Number other that `0` and `10` are panic. I still confused and not understand. Can someone explain what `base` is used for in `ParseInt()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting a string to an integer. The method is asking you for the base (number system) the string is in. You can learn more about number systems here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix

For example (using your code snippet provided [here](https://play.golang.org/p/TfZApCpqfx)):

```
var s string = "1111" // This string is in binary (Base 2)
i, err := strconv.ParseInt(s, 2, 64) // Give the base as 2
```

Result:

```
Hello, 15 with type int64!
```

Comment: I really asked a stupid question, but thank you for your answer. it helps me.